# How to get rid of heterogeneity of variance?

Tags: anova, heteroscedasticity

I'm measuring the impact of three different types of videos on vocabulary learning (the dependent variable). Participants were divided into three different groups. Each group watched one type of video and took 4 vocabulary tests. I tried to conduct a two way ANOVA conduct to see which type of video was the most beneficial. I also wanted to know if gender is a factor. The problem that I'm facing is that the groups are not homogeneous based on Levene's test. The second problem is that I could not find a way to compare all tests with three groups and account for gender at the same time.

My questions:

- How to get rid of homogeneity?
- Is there a better test to use to achieve my objectives mentioned above?

---

I’m running a one way ANOVA with the dependent list (4 types of tests: oral vocabulary recognition,  written vocabulary recognition, oral vocabulary recall and written vocabulary recall) and factor is (group).  I have three groups: no caption group (n=23), keyword caption group (n=23) and full caption group (n=24). I’m trying to compare the scores of each test type on each group.  For some reason, the groups proved to be homogeneous when I balanced the number of participants in each group. Is running a one way ANOVA appropriate? How do I find out if there is a difference between males (n=40) and females (n=31)?

Comment: What do you mean that you "could not find a way to compare all tests with three groups and account for gender at the same time"? Are you running 4 separate ANOVAs for the 4 vocabulary tests, or are you combining the 4 tests into a single score? What is your N? Are the data balanced? What are the minimum & maximum SDs for the groups?

Comment: If you aren't comfortable doing an ANOVA you can consider the Kruskal-Wallis test which is a nonparametric alternative: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%E2%80%93Wallis_one-way_analysis_of_variance

Comment: Does vocabulary learning make up 1 or 4 dependent variables?  If 4, this could be a case for repeated-measures ANOVA.

Comment: You can apply a Welch-Satterthwaite type procedure akin to what is commonly done for the t-test. Unfortunately, because you've *tested* for heteroskedasticity, your procedures no longer have their nominal properties (it's better simply not to assume constant variance).

Comment: I assume you mean *heterogeneity* (and specifically, heterogeneity of variance), not *homogeneity* (having the same variance in each group is not a problem!!). Please fix.

Comment: The title was fixed but the body text wasn't....

Answer (score 1):

You can apply a Welch-Satterthwaite type procedure akin to what is commonly done for the t-test. Unfortunately, because you've *tested* for heteroskedasticity, your procedures no longer have their nominal properties (it's better simply not to assume constant variance if you can't make the assumption).

Alternatively, if your sample sizes are equal, the ordinary ANOVA isn't sensitive to the assumption so in that case you could simply ignore it.

[Alternatively-alternatively, if on a prior considerations you can argue that the spread would be related to the mean in some fashion, you could consider a GLM. I expect that the spreads would increase with the mean, and might consider a Gamma GLM (or possibly a negative binomial if some of the scores might be small).]